# How to set the bottomsheet to the top of bottom navigationview

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, android-nestedscrollview

I am trying to show the bottom sheet along with the BottomNavigationview.
[image: But overlapping. Check Here]

How I will give bottom margin to the Bottom sheet.

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/bottomSheetRecyclerview"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Implementation code:

```
 override fun openBottomDialogView() {

        val bottomSheetView= findViewById<NestedScrollView>(R.id.bottomSheet) as NestedScrollView
        Log.e("Bottom sheet view ",bottomSheetView.toString())


         dashboardBottomSheetBehaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetView)
            dashboardBottomSheetBehaviour.isHideable=true

        if(dashboardBottomSheetBehaviour.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {

            bottomSheetRecyclerview.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(this@DashboardActivity) as RecyclerView.LayoutManager?
            bottomSheetRecyclerview.adapter= BottomSheetDialogAdaptor(this@DashboardActivity, getBottomSheetitem())
            dashboardBottomSheetBehaviour.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
        else {
            closeBottomView()
        }
    }
```

I tried to set the fixed height of nestedscrollview and then give margin but that also didn't work.

About new issues I am facing

```
fun closedBottomView(){
     Log.e("CLose ","Old bottom sheet")
        dashboardBottomSheetBehaviour.state=BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN
        Log.e("Final state ",dashboardBottomSheetBehaviour.state.toString())

}
```

Here final log says bottom sheet state is in STATE_SETTLING. But callback says it in HIDDEN state.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:`layout_anchor` for your `BottomNavigationView` to anchor it on top/bottom of your `BottomSheetView`

```
 app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottomSheet" --> BottomSheet view ID
 app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
```

For more info you can look at [This Link](https://medium.com/android-bits/android-anchoring-views-to-bottom-sheet-9c9069caf7d4)

Comment: That solved my problem but created the new issues . Now the bottom sheet is not collapsing.

Comment: Set A peek Height on your BottomSheet...and override the Callback method  to find out which state it is in..see this:http://android-er.blogspot.com/2016/06/sets-height-of-collapsed-bottom-sheet.html

Comment: I think  I don't need to override the callback method since I am controlling show/hide state of the sheet using the fab.

Comment: i mean to say for debugging purposes...cause i don't find a cause for it to be  not collapsing..

Answer (score 0):

My way around this is to wrap my original bottomsheet with a view and set the size of that topmost view with 72dp(approximatively the size of the bottom navigation bar) more.
Example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="184dp"
app:behavior_hideable="true"
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="112dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_transparent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewThumbnailMap"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewThumbnailDistance"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewThumbnailName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewThumbnailMap"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="5km" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewThumbnailName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewThumbnailDateTime"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewThumbnailMap"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewThumbnailDistance"
        tools:text="Karaoke golos" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewThumbnailDateTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.SearchResult.Subtitle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewThumbnailMap"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewThumbnailName"
        tools:text="19:30-23:50" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]